# Repost of parts of an answer as new answer

Tags: discussion

I posted an [A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42822723/1505120) to  [Press Overview Button in Android Espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42819656/press-overview-button-in-android-espresso/42822723) and a [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42829083/1505120) (10k+) was posted a day later that, in my opinion, is a repost of my answer with small additions: it contains the same code and explanation as mine but also two additional links (that point to general information about the topic but nothing specific to the Q).

I raised a flag because I thought it would be better to edit my post if any formulation is not clear, instead of reposting the essential aspects. The flag was declined.

What is the preferred Stack Overflow way in such a case:

- Reposting something as a new answer because I think my phrasing is better, or
- make an edit suggestion to the original answer?

and regarding the "you voted me down" accusations, is there any thing to do against that?

Comment: `But the flag was declined by the author of the second answer himself.` That user isn't a moderator, and so isn't capable of declining such a flag.  Additionally, you're not told who declines your flags, so you wouldn't have any way of knowing who declined the flag even if they *did* do it (which they didn't).

Comment: Ah okay sorry then I misinterpreted the UI where it says my flag was declined.

Comment: The comments by that user (now deleted) really aren't helping their case...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> second answer that is a repost of the original answer with small additions:

If that *were* the case, I could see there being a problem (if it doesn't cite the content from the other answer appropriately, or doesn't provide much or any original content, it could be a case of plagiarism), but I don't see that as being the case here at all.  The (very, very short) code snippets are the same, and they're specifically cited as having been posted by you.  The crux of both answers however is not the short code snippet, but the explanation, and each of them is original.  It's entirely appropriate to post an answer that uses a similar, or even the same, solution as another answer, but that contains an original explanation of the problem and/or the solution.

Now in this particular case the other user's explanation seems very poor, so you may consider downvoting it on that basis, but I don't see any evidence of plagiarism, and the basic idea of posting another answer isn't in any way problematic (at least if it were good).

The assertion that the OP should have edited their additional content into your answer is incorrect.  Such an edit would merit rejection.  Edits are there to improve the presentation of someone else's answer, not to edit your own original content into their answer.  They could have commented on your answer if there were certain things they wish were explained better, or provided some information that they'd like you to include, but posting their own explanation as their own answer is perfectly fine.